# Подвергать критике страну за надежность в качестве партнера - как понимать?

Tags: стилистика

Как понимать выражения:

1. "Подвергать критике страну за надежность в качестве партнера"
2. "Подвергать критике страну за ненадежность в качестве партнера"?

Обычно подвергают критике за что-то плохое.

Согласно словарю, критика - обсуждение, разбор чего-н. с целью оценить, выявить недостатки.

Если говорят: подвергать критике страну за надежность в качестве партнера - это значит не хотят назвать ненадежным партнером, но пытаются выявить недостатки?

Answer (score 1):

"Подвергать критике" - в данном контексте это формальный вариант бытового "ругать"; за что? - за ненадёжность (за плохое), поэтому правильное выражение - под п. 2.

Comment: Простите, что не по теме. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, ответ grizzly про "без ничего". Очень хочется понять, можно так выражаться или всё-таки лучше этого самому избегать.

Comment: Я добавил комментарий в тему.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я там же ответил на тот комментарий.